# Using a variable outside of the while loop (scope)

Tags: php, loops, scope, while-loop

Small problem regarding scope in PHP, I can't seem to call the variable $report outside of the while loop. I have tried various things, including `return`. This doesn't work, the only two functions that work here are if I `echo` the variable `$report` inside the loop, or if I `print` it. Which I do not want to do, although it solves the problem, but I don't want random gibberish on the user's screen.

I have been looking around for the last 15 or so minutes, and I haven't seen any problems quite like this one on here.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?
require "functions2.php";
require "members.php";
$query = "SELECT MAX(DOCid) as prevDOCid from reports";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prevDOCid = $row[prevDOCid];

$thisDOCid = $prevDOCid+1;
$report = "a"."b".$thisDOCid;


}
echo $report;
?>
```

Comment: if you are echo ing $report inside while loop , do you get any op?

Comment: PHP doesn't really have a concept of scope like, say, Java's where this would be a problem. If `$report` is not declared by the time you get to the `echo` statement, I am guessing PHP never enters the `while` loop in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, well it's not working. I am obviously not just trying to echo the $report, I am just posting the code this way for simplicity's sake. The only way I can use the variable outside of the loop is if I echo it first.

Comment: PS: You really shouldn't be using `$row[prevDOCid]`. Use quotes: `$row['prevDOCid']`. It might work, but [it's wrong](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).

Comment: Define "not working." Does it give you unexpected output? If so, what did you expect? Does it say it's undefined? What?

Comment: It gives undefined variable, that's correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try to define the variable before the loop, e.g.

```
$report = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $report .= "a"."b".$row["prevDOCid"]+1;
}
echo $report;
```

I hope this helps you!

Edit Use .= not +=

Comment: @RVward You are wrong. They *can* be declared in the loop and be used outside of it. Here's [proof](http://codepad.org/508BRBCi). The difference is this concatenates new values to `$report`, instead of just overwriting it with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @RVWard Interesting. So if you run the script exactly as it is in your question, it will tell you `$report` is undefined?

Comment: What result do you actually expect? Purhaps in the last loop you just override the variable with a null value...

Comment: @Vilius what if I want to access this var on the top of the while loop is it possible?