# Get cumulative total amount (by addition) of while() loop amounts from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

My query etc is working perfectly fine, but I am unable to get an added total of the results in a variable to echo out.

With what I have below, I keep getting a 0 (zero) amount in the $full_total; value.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($all_donations)) {
        $donation_date = date("m/d/Y", $row['date']);
            echo "<tr><td>" . $donation_date ."</td><td>" . number_format($row['price'], 2) ."</td></tr>";

            $total_dontations = number_format($row['price'], 2);
            $full_total += $total_donations;
      }
// echo this amount outside of the loop.
echo $full_total;
```

Comment: you might want to delete the question - since you write everywhere you had a typo and it's resolved without the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing full_total

```
$full_total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($all_donations)) {
//...
```

Comment: You need a semicolon after `$full_total = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `$full_total` above the your `while` statement like this:

```
$full_total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($all_donations))
{ ...
```

Comment: I initialized the counter (makes sense to do so) no luck, but realized I have a typo! $total_dontations (dontations) ...

Comment: That would do it! Those simple typos get me all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think its similiar with [Using a variable outside of the while loop (scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337743/using-a-variable-outside-of-the-while-loop-scope)

According that thread, you can go like this

```
$full_total = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($all_donations)) {
        $donation_date = date("m/d/Y", $row['date']);
            echo "<tr><td>" . $donation_date ."</td><td>" . number_format($row['price'], 2) ."</td></tr>";

            $total_dontations = number_format($row['price'], 2);
            $full_total += $total_donations;
      }
// echo this amount outside of the loop.
echo $full_total;
```

Comment: I ended up initializing in the exact format of the results like this: $full_total = number_format(0.00, 2);