# Store a variable unchanged outside of the while loop

Tags: php, store, var

I don't know if I will be able to formulate my question the way may be understood, but I will try.

I have this php code and I'm interested in "take off" the last variable from the while  loop!!

```
$c= "2040-01-01 12:00:00";
$d= "2040-01-02 12:00:00";
$date_3 = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime("$c"));
$date_4 = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime("$d"));

$results = array($date_1);
$i = $date_3;

while ($i <= $date_4) {
    $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime($i));
    array_push($results, $i);
    $k= $i . "\n";
    $chunks = str_split($k, 19);
    $nexstring = join('\')', $chunks);
    $cane = implode(', (\'', str_split($nexstring, 21));
    echo $cane; // OUTPUTS -> 2040-01-01 12:00:00'), (' 2040-01-02 12:00:00'), (' 
    $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($i)));
}
echo $cane; // OUTPUTS -> 2040-01-02 12:00:00'), ('
```

Now my question is

why $cane echo me something different outside of the while{} and how should I store this variable to be the same outside of the while{}?

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: do you want to remove the last result added to $result ? Do you want to have the last value of a specific variable declared inside the while loop ?

Comment: `$cane` changes each time the loop happens.  when the loop ends, `$cane` will be equal to the last value it was assigned inside of the loop.

Comment: similar to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337743/using-a-variable-outside-of-the-while-loop-scope

Comment: I would like that $cane echo me the same outside of the while scope!

Comment: which 'version' of $cane? every loop it changes. do you want the first? last? third?

Comment: Actually it does :D What you got wron is what it'S doing INSIDE the loop. It's not outputting all of that at once - it'S doing that one after another. See my answer.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin It seems not. you may see I wrote that the output is different outside the loop

Comment: ok i'm going to edit  the question with the whole code I have so u may give a try. My intent is to output the same outside the while loop. Nothing else..

Comment: No, @gloomy.penguin is totally right. It does never contain all that stuff at once. Never, not even inside the loop. It only contains one of those values at a time. If you want to accumulate all values, you have to accumulate them in one variable - not overwriting it every time.

Comment: @user2988759 - your loop outputs the value of `$cane` several times.  you don't have a line break so it appears all together.  `$cane` is only ever one value at a time, though. do this:  `echo $cane."<br/>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $cane` only outputs one of that values at a time. But it'S inside the loop, so it runs multiple times - that's the only reason why you got all those values. Of course if you echo `$cane` outside the loop again, it will only contain the last value you put in there - previous ones have been outputted, but overridden.

You'll have to append all those values to one variables inside the loop if they should be availabe outside:

```
$allCane="";
while ($i <= $date_4) {
    $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime($i));
    array_push($results, $i);
    $k= $i . "\n";
    $chunks = str_split($k, 19);
    $nexstring = join('\')', $chunks);
    $cane = implode(', (\'', str_split($nexstring, 21));
    echo $cane;
    $allCane .= $cane; // appends $cane to $allCane
    $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($i)));
}
echo $allCane;
```

Or, as pointed out by Dagon, you could store all those values inside one array:

```
$allCane = array();
for ( /* ... */ ) {
    // ...
    $allCane[] = $cane;
    // ...
}
/*
   $allCane is now

   array (
      [0] = "2040-01-01 12:00:00'), (' ",
      [1] = "2040-01-02 12:00:00'), (' ",
      ...
   )
*/
```

Comment: Yep, possible too. But harder to output - I didn't want to do too much at once. I'll add it in as an alternative.

Comment: @Johannes H. Thank you, but I get php error on the last line inside the loop. Unexpected T_variable. Should you kindly re-edit the way it works, I'm quite nearby.

Comment: That's strange, I don'T see any syntax error in my code... can somebody else please look for it? I never see my one booboos ;)

Comment: Ah. That's why I missed it  was fixed already ^^ Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run this code to see stuff a little better:

```
$results = array($date_1);
$i       = $date_3;

$cane    = "";  
$count   = 0; 

while ($i <= $date_4) 
{
    $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime($i));
    array_push($results, $i);
    $k= $i . "\n";
    $chunks = str_split($k, 19);
    $nexstring = join('\')', $chunks);

    // assign a new value to $cane 
    $cane = implode(', (\'', str_split($nexstring, 21));

    echo "Loop $count:  $cane <br/>";  

    $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($i)));

    $count++;
}

echo "After loop:  $cane";
```