# PHP MySQL How to get variable created in while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I just started learning php, i have a long way to go but i really need help with this.

So I have a page where a logged in user can create tasks and that user can select the user for who the task is. I need to do an insert query where i'll need the ID of the person selected by the user who is logged in.

This is the code that's above my HTML:

```
$userId = $_SESSION['id'];

$Users = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Result2 = $db->query($Users);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$project = $_POST['Project'];
$task = $_POST['task'];
$user = $_POST['User'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO events (projectId, userId, name, date)
              VALUES ('','', '$task', '$date')";

    $result = $database->query($query);
    echo "it worked";



}
```

This is the code in my HTML select tag, where the logged in user can select the person.

```
<?php

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result2)) {
       $uid = $row2['id'];
       $name = $row2['name'];
       $lastName = $row2['lastname'];

       echo "<option>" . $name . " " . $lastName . " " . $uid . "</option>";
         }


 ?>
```

The problem is that I need to put the `$uid` variable, that's currently in the whileloop in my HTML select element, IN the first if statement above my HTML. I have tried everything but i cant seem to figure out how. It perfectly shows all of the users and their ID numbers, I just need to grab them and put them in my if statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337743/using-a-variable-outside-of-the-while-loop-scope

Comment: I tried giving it a empty variable and then echoing it, but it doesnt work...

Comment: `<option value="$uid"> .... ` then it should be available in `$_POST['whateveryourselectfieldiscalled']`

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I have been stuck to this all day you made my day!

Comment: gotta hate the simple ones you can't see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<option>`tags are surely in a `<select>` tag. You have to give a name to your select, and that name will be the POST parameter name you can use in your PHP server-side code.
Also, you have to assign a value attribute to each option.

Your HTML print procedure become

```
<?php

echo '<select name="uid">';
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result2)) {
       $uid = $row2['id'];
       $name = $row2['name'];
       $lastName = $row2['lastname'];

       echo "<option value='".$uid."'>" . $name . " " . $lastName . " " . $uid . "</option>";
         }
echo '</select>';  

 ?>
```

and you PHP server-side code become

```
$userId = $_SESSION['id'];

$Users = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Result2 = $db->query($Users);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$project = $_POST['Project'];
$task = $_POST['task'];
$user = $_POST['User'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$uid = $_POST["uid"];

$query = "INSERT INTO events (projectId, userId, name, date) VALUES ('','', '$task', '$date')";
$result = $database->query($query);
echo "it worked";
}
```

If you're learning PHP, I advise to start correctly. Never access your superglobal parameters $_GET and $_POST directly without sanitize your inputs. Use some functions like [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: if you're going to mention sanitising data, you could at least mention `prepared statements` and `parameter binding`, as well as some indication of WHY to do this.

Comment: Of course, but not in this case. He said he's learning, it's useless to give a 10-pages long answer for a question like this. Maybe he's already aware about this, I've only given a link where he can study in his own way. If he wants to go deeper, he can open another dedicated question; sanitising inputs is not a matter that you can discuss fleetingly.

Comment: i disagree. simply saying 'never do this' and 'always do that' are useless without a basic description of 'why'.

Comment: I didn't say "never do this" in any case, I said it after viewing a sourcecode where he's putting POST variables directly in his DB. And no, in this case there are no exceptions since you are receiving your inputs by an HTML form. Anyway, I respect your POV, even if I disagree.