# How to pull data from database and assign to a variable to make delete query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to pull data from a database and then assign the returned result to a variable for the purpose of doing another search / deleting, but I keep getting an error message saying the variables I set up ($islecturer and $group) are undefined. If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong here I would be very grateful.

```
<?php

require ('mysqli_connect.php');

        $q1 = "SELECT `islecturer` FROM `participants` WHERE `uninum` = 'A17'";
        $result1 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q1);


while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $islecturer = $row1['islecturer'];

       echo $islecturer;

}


       if ($islecturer == 0){

        $q2 = "SELECT `groupid` FROM `groups` WHERE `uninum` = 'A17'";
        $result2 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q2);

      }  

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $group = $row2['groupid'];

       echo $group;

}

         $q3 = "DELETE FROM `schedule` WHERE `groupid` = $group LIMIT 1;";
            $result3 = mysqli_multi_query ($dbcon , $q3);
         $q3 .="DELETE FROM `groups` WHERE `groupid` = $group LIMIT 1;";
            $result3 = mysqli_multi_query ($dbcon , $q3);
         $q3 .="DELETE FROM `individualavailability` WHERE uninum = 'A17' LIMIT 1;";
            $result3 = mysqli_multi_query ($dbcon , $q3);
         $q3 .="DELETE FROM `availabilityindex` WHERE `uninum` = 'A17' LIMIT 1;";
            $result3 = mysqli_multi_query ($dbcon , $q3);
         $q3 ="DELETE FROM `participants` WHERE `uninum` = 'A17' LIMIT 1;";
            $result3 = mysqli_multi_query ($dbcon , $q3);


         if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbcon ) > 1) { // If it ran OK.
            echo 'Successfully deleted';
         }

        else if ($islecturer == 1){ 
        echo 'you can\'t delete a lecturer without adding a replacement group member';
        }
        else{
            echo 'query failed';
        }


mysqli_close($dbcon );

?>
```

Comment: Just to note that 'A17' is hard coded at the moment, but it will be obtained from $_POST['uni_id'].

Answer (score 1):

The `$islecturer` and `$group` variables are defined in another scope, namely in the scope of their while loop. Outside of the while loop you can't access them anymore.

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $islecturer = $row1['islecturer'];
       echo $islecturer;
} 
// Out of scope, $islecturer is not accessible anymore
```

EDIT : To solve this problem you can define the variable before the loop.

```
$islecturer = 0;
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $islecturer = $row1['islecturer'];
       echo $islecturer;
}

if ($islecturer == 0){
   ...
}
```

Note that with a little of research you would have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337743/using-a-variable-outside-of-the-while-loop-scope) link which is nearly exact the same problem as you are facing.

Comment: Many thanks HyperZ! Could I ask if you know a good way to get around this issue? I have been trying to pass the database column names / values into a function as a parameter which does the sqli query and returns the result which I thought i could assign to a variable, but with little success!