# $ROW = Undefined?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting

> "Undefined variable: row" for the following code at the "        return ($row);"

Isn't `$ROW` defined at `$ROW[] = Array(...)`?

```js
 <?php
    function fetchImageState(){
        $state = $_GET['state'];
        global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT athletedetails.UserID,
     athletedetails.State_Code,
     filesrepository.user_id,
     filesrepository.new_file_name,
     filesrepository.file_ID
    FROM athletedetails INNER JOIN filesrepository ON athletedetails.UserID = filesrepository.user_id
    WHERE athletedetails.State_Code = '$state'
      ");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($UserID, $statecode, $user, $file_id, $new_file_name);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){
            $row[] = array(
                'userID' => $UserID,
                'state' => $statecode,
                'user' => $user,
                'fileid' => $file_id,
                'newfilename' => $new_file_name);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return ($row);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){` or just use `fetch_all`? You also are open to SQL injections with this code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable outside of the while loop (scope)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337743/using-a-variable-outside-of-the-while-loop-scope)

Comment: @chris85 thanks for the input, this code is for a class and we were told not to worry so much about security. Completely aware the "get" code isn't good practice. But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

$row needs to be defined before the while statement. It currently only exists within the scope of the while statement and is destroyed before returning.

**N.B.** $row may not contain the values you're expecting to be returned. But I also don't work in PHP often and it may.

Answer (score 0):

As Stevoni says, you should declare the `$row` array before your while loop. However, it's not that there a scope issue. Your `$stmt->fetch()` is probably returning false, so the block in the while loop is never entered, and therefore the `$row` variable is never created.