# PHP Select From Database And Display IF Variable Exists

Tags: php

I'm starting a small online site which has content in an "issue". Here is my code to collect that:

```
<?php
$issue_sql = "SELECT * FROM issues WHERE id = '$id'"; // From URL
$issue_res = mysqli_query($con, $issue_sql);
while($issue = mysqli_fetch_assoc($issue_res)){

    $issue_id = $issue["id"];
    $issue_added = $issue["added"];
    $issue_content = $issue["content"];
    $issue_endorsed = $issue["endorsed"];

    $issue_year = date("Y", strtotime($issue_added));
    $issue_date = date("l jS F, Y", strtotime($issue_added));

}
?>
```

And I want to `display` the endorsement only if it exists (Which in this case it does). So my code for this is:

```
<?php
if($issue_endorsed === 1){
    $endorsed_sql = "SELECT article FROM issue_endorsed WHERE id = '$issue_id'";
    $endorsed_res = mysqli_query($con, $endorsed_sql);
    while($endorsed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($endorsed_res)){

        $endorsed_article = $endorsed["article"];

        $display_endorsed = "

            <div class=\"section\">
                <div class=\"sectionText\">
                    <b>We Recommend ...</b>
                    <br>
                    ... $endorsed_article
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=\"contentDivideSecondary\"></div>

        ";

    }
}else{
    $display_endorsed = "Not Here";
};
?>
```

The problem is, when I `<?php echo display_endorsed; ?>` later on in the html code, I'm shown the `Not Here` instead of the actual content. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements with mysqli or PDO

Comment: Are you using register globals?

Comment: @ctwheels Please lets forget the SQL until we work on a solution. Thanks

Comment: @AdamForbis As I don't know what that is, I asume not!

Comment: Is your `$issue_endorsed` variable a integer or a string?

Comment: @WayneSix I would argue that protecting yourself against such attacks is actually more important than the application even working in the first place (unless it's so broken it just spews out all the database information). Writing the code well using prepared statements is a starting point, not an ending point. You should be coding the entire application taking security seriously

Comment: @AdamForbis It's a 0 or 1

Comment: but as an integer or a string? It matters if you use `===`, use `var_dump` to tell

Comment: In my database I store it as a 1 or a 0. 1 if the endorsement exists, and 0 if not!

Comment: I'm betting it's returning a string version of 0 or 1, I could be wrong though

Comment: @AdamForbis Well, I changed it from `===` to `==` and it's now working fine, so I guess there was an issue in there somewhere. Thanks

Comment: @WayneSix You are setting the variable within the scope of the `while` loop, thus it does not exist in the global scope. Also, it's not clear whether these two scripts are separate or part of the same program.

Comment: @ctwheels They are part of the same. Problem is solved now anyway by changing the `===` to `==`

Comment: @WayneSix unless you've declared the `$issue_endorsed` variable in the same scope as the if statement, your code isn't actually running properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337743/using-a-variable-outside-of-the-while-loop-scope

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @ctwheels How can you say it's not working when it's clearly showing up on my screen?

Comment: @ctwheels Actually it is in the same scope, the variables will escape the while loop, and since they are in the same file, and not in different functions...

Comment: @AdamForbis you are correct, my apologies. It seemed like a scope issue since both code samples were posted separately.

Comment: @ctwheels I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you where having has to do with one main thing. MySQL was likely returning the database value of the column `endorsed` as a string. Now your if statement:

`if($issue_endorsed === 1){`

is doing an identity comparison. Saying is `$issue_endorsed` identical to an integer of 1? This was not true because the database was returning it as a string. Switching this to `==` fixed the issue because it type juggles the string `"1"` into the integer `1` before the comparison.

The main points to remember out of an issue like this are

1. PHP is not a typeless language, it is a dynamic one. There are still types, they are just really easy to swap between most of the time.
2. It is normally a safe to assume that a database returns everything as a string(Certain database options won't though).

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Adam